# Approximating Standard Normal

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, mean, central-limit-theorem

If the sampling distribution of the mean is approximately normal (by the Central Limit Theorem), does this mean that when you standardize it the standard normal is also an approximation?

Answer (score 2):

If by standardizing you mean subtracting sample mean $\bar x$ and dividing by sample standard deviation $s$ then it is always equal to zero

$$ \operatorname{Mean}(x-\bar x) = \frac{x_1 - \bar x + \dots + x_n - \bar x}{n} =\\ \frac{x_1 + \dots + x_n}{n} - \frac{n \bar x}{n} = \bar x - \bar x = 0 $$

so it's not random anymore.